# What happens when we send message to id

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

As the documents in Apple Website says, when we send message to a class variable which extends NSObject, it means we call objc_msgSend function and look up the method in the class's method table. If not found, it go through its superclass until it reaches NSObject.
However,it seems it will behave different when we send message to id as this blog said:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html

What does it mean by looking up all the methods? 
Can anyone tell me the detail?

Comment: not sure, but java's dynamic method lookup determines the runtime class of the object and calls the method based on what class the object is at that point in time. i'm assuming that's what obj-c does as well, but i can't seem to find anything with a quick search on google. maybe dig a little deeper into this?

Comment: er, it seems nobody knows more about it?

Comment: Java operates static - all method binding happens at compile time. Objective-c is dynamic - binds methods at runtime using the class identity (isa  pointer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems I misunderstand the runtime lookup and compile lookup.
during compile， what the compiler needs is the signature of method, so it looks up it by the class type. Sending message to id means compiler should look up all exists methods.
during runtime, what the runtime do is look up the real address of imp by information of "what the class is".